# How can we be sure there is a random variable independent of some given random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

Given a sequence of (say) independent real-valued random variables $ \lbrace X_n \rbrace _{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, does there exist a random variable $T$ that is *independent of the whole sequence* $ \lbrace X_n \rbrace _{n=1}^{\infty}$ and is  defined on *the same probability space*?

This is one of the common situations when we often just say: let $T$ be a random variable that is independent of ... (some other variables) But how do we know we can construct such a variable on the same probability space?

I am aware of the canonical contruction: for a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ there is a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P):= (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{B}^n,\mu)$ and a random variable $X := id_{\Omega}$ such that $P_X = \mu.$ So for our problem I would think that using this concept for the measure $P_T \bigotimes \otimes P_{X_n}$ and thus finding a random variable $U$ with this distribution and then putting $T:= U_1$ would work but then again, isn't there a problem with the underlying probability spaces?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct examples where it doesn't work, e.g. $\Omega = \mathbb{N}$ and $X_n=\mathbb{1}_{\{n\}}$.

But you can always enlarge $\Omega$ so that it does work without changing any of the properties that we're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide an example of how exactly we would do the enlarging process? :-)

Comment: Sure. If we have $T$ and $X_n$ defined on $\Omega$ and we want $T$ to be independent of the $X_n$, then we can switch to $\Omega'=\Omega\times\Omega$ with the $X_n$ defined on the first $\Omega$ and the $T$ defined on the second. The variables have the same distribution as before but are now independent.

Comment: I don't see how this could work. First, does $\Omega \times \Omega$ contain $\Omega$? Second, what would be the new sigma algebra and probability measure, would they be $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{A}$ and $P^2$?